# Allow ALL method types in flask route

Tags: python, flask

How can I allow a route to accept all types of methods?

I don't just want to route the standard methods like `HEAD`, `GET`, `POST`, `OPTIONS`, `DELETE` & `PUT`.

I would like it to also accept the following methods: `FOOBAR`, `WHYISTHISMETHODNAMESOLONG` & **every other** possible method names.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can change the url_map directly for this, by adding a [`Rule`](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/routing/#werkzeug.routing.Rule) with no methods:

```
from flask import Flask, request
import unittest
from werkzeug.routing import Rule

app = Flask(__name__)
app.url_map.add(Rule('/', endpoint='index'))

@app.endpoint('index')
def index():
    return request.method


class TestMethod(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.client = app.test_client()

    def test_custom_method(self):
        resp = self.client.open('/', method='BACON')
        self.assertEqual('BACON', resp.data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

> `methods`
>
> A sequence of http methods this rule applies to. If not specified, all methods are allowed.

Answer (score 14):

To quickly enable all [HTTP Request Methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods) for a `route` without manually adding rules to the Flask `url_map`, modify the `route` definition as follows:

```
from flask import request

HTTP_METHODS = ['GET', 'HEAD', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE', 'CONNECT', 'OPTIONS', 'TRACE', 'PATCH']


@app.route('/', methods=HTTP_METHODS)
def index():
  return request.method
```

Answer (score 2):

See below, which is some code (that I've trimmed down) [from the Flask app object](https://github.com/mitsuhiko/flask/blob/master/flask/app.py#L949). This code handles adding a url rule (which is also what is called by flask when you do app.route() on your view)....

```
@setupmethod
def add_url_rule(self, rule, endpoint=None, view_func=None, **options):
    """ I remove a ton the documentation here.... """

    if endpoint is None:
        endpoint = _endpoint_from_view_func(view_func)
    options['endpoint'] = endpoint
    methods = options.pop('methods', None)

    # if the methods are not given and the view_func object knows its
    # methods we can use that instead.  If neither exists, we go with
    # a tuple of only `GET` as default.
    if methods is None:
        methods = getattr(view_func, 'methods', None) or ('GET',)
    methods = set(methods)

    # ... SNIP a bunch more code...
    rule = self.url_rule_class(rule, methods=methods, **options)
    rule.provide_automatic_options = provide_automatic_options

    self.url_map.add(rule)
```

As you can see, Flask will do it's darndest to ensure that the methods are explicitely defined. Now, Flask is based on Werkzeug, and the line...

```
rule = self.url_rule_class(rule, methods=methods, **options)
```

...typically uses [Werkzeug's Rule](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/routing/#werkzeug.routing.Rule) class. This class has the following documentation for the "methods" argument...

> A sequence of http methods this rule applies to. If not specified, all
>   methods are allowed.

So, this tells me that you MIGHT be able to do something like the following...

```
from werkzeug.routing import Rule

app = Flask(__name__)

def my_rule_wrapper(rule, **kwargs):
    kwargs['methods'] = None
    return Rule(rule, **kwargs)

app.url_rule_class = my_rule_wrapper
```

I haven't tested this out, but hopefully that can get you on the right track.

**Edit:**

Or you could just use DazWorrall's answer, which seems better :P

Comment: Changing the url_rule_class will work as well :) Its probably cleaner if you wanted to open many (or all) routes up to any method.

Answer (score 0):

Mark Hildreth's answer can be minified to one line... If you want to sacrifice a bit code readability :D

```py
app = Flask(__name__)
app.url_rule_class = lambda rule, **kwargs: Rule(rule, **{**kwargs, 'methods': None})
```