# Changing request method using hidden field _method in Flask

Tags: python, flask, werkzeug

Started picking up Python and Flask as a learning exercise, and coming from PHP/Symfony2, I could add a hidden _method field to a form to override the POST method with either a DELETE or PUT.

It seems Flask doesn't support this natively, and I've been hacking around with various ideas including http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/38/, which works, but involves putting the override in the form action, rather than as a hidden field, which IMO makes the URL look unsightly.

There is a snippet in the comments of the above address, which makes _method work from a routing perspective, but as discussed there as well, does cause the request to hang if you then try to access request.form in the views.

Does anyone have a workaround for this? If not, I'll just handle everything as POST, but would be nice to be able to find a way to get it to work.

Cheers.

---

**EDIT:** Here's the code for anyone who wants to take a look:

Template:

```
<form action="{{ url_for('login') }}" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
    <input class="span12" name="email" type="text" placeholder="E-mail address" value="{{ email }}">
    <input class="span12" name="password" type="password" placeholder="Your password">
    <a href="{{ url_for('reset_password') }}" class="forgot">Forgot password?</a>
    <div class="remember">
        <input id="remember-me" type="checkbox">
        <label for="remember-me">Remember me</label>
    </div>
    <input class="btn-glow primary login" type="submit" name="submit" value="Log in">
</form>
```

app/__init__.py

```
from flask import Flask
from werkzeug.wrappers import Request

class MethodRewriteMiddleware(object):
    def __init__(self, app, input_name='_method'):
        self.app = app
        self.input_name = input_name

    def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
        request = Request(environ)

        if self.input_name in request.form:
            method = request.form[self.input_name].upper()

            if method in ['GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE']:
                environ['REQUEST_METHOD'] = method

        return self.app(environ, start_response)

app = Flask(__name__)
app.wsgi_app = MethodRewriteMiddleware(app.wsgi_app)
from app import views
```

View:

```
from flask import render_template
@app.route('/user/login', methods=['GET','POST','PUT'])
def login():
    emailvalue = 'test@test.com'
    if request.method == 'PUT':
        emailvalue = request.form['email']
    return render_template('login.html', email=emailvalue)
```

Comment: [request.form](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/quickstart/#the-request-object) might be of some use to you.

Comment: Hi @johnthexiii, thanks for your comment. I'm actually using request.form already to check whether _method is set, but once I do that and change the REQUEST_METHOD in the middleware, I can't access request.form in the views (the app just hangs).

This is the link with the suggestion I was trying: http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/38/#comment-box (second comment)

Comment: I've put some code up to give a better overview of what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: If you're happy checking the method from the form field, would this answer regarding routing all methods to an endpoint help? http://stackoverflow.com/a/16612377/1949092 `method = request.form.get('_method', request.method); if method == 'PUT': ...`

Comment: Thanks @DazWorrall, you could do that, but I would like a way to have the method permeate throughout the framework, and have separate view functions and route decorators for each HTTP verb for maintainability, keeping the functions simple, and not having to rely on if logic just to route requests. I'd like the framework to do _all_ the routing if at all possible.

Comment: you may be abusing "PUT"

Comment: What I don't get is why you want to do this in the first case. Why not directly change the GET into a PUT by the python code that adds the hidden form field? `<form action="{{ url_for('login') }}" method={{method|default("POST")}}>`. Now call render_form(..., method="DELETE") and you're done.

Comment: @HolgerSchurig, browsers don't support the DELETE and PUT verbs as methods in a <form> tag, the conversion needs to happen server side.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As you already pointed out, your middleware makes the later `request.form` empty. This is because `request.form` is reading from a file-like object. Quoting [PEP 333](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0333/#environ-variables):

> wsgi.input -- An input stream (file-like object) from which the HTTP request body can be read. (The server or gateway may perform reads on-demand as requested by the application, or it may pre- read the client's request body and buffer it in-memory or on disk, or use any other technique for providing such an input stream, according to its preference.)

Note that this paragraph doesn't tell us if this "file-like object" will provide any possibility to reset the pointer to the beginning of the file. In fact, if we try the following application:

```
from werkzeug.serving import run_simple

def app(environ, start_response):
    start_response('200 OK', [('Content-Type', 'text/plain')])
    yield str(dir(environ['wsgi.input']))

run_simple('localhost', 5000, app)
```

It doesn't show any indices that this file object has a `seek` method.

So, what you *could do* is read everything into a bytestring called `data`, and replace `wsgi.input` with `BytesIO(data)`, which does have a `seek` method one can use. **Doing this brings several disadvantages with it**, the most obvious being that all uploaded data is guaranteed to get completely read into memory before passing it to the application. Probably there are also some **dangerous edge cases** that i don't know myself of, which is why i never would risk trying the following in a real application:

```
from werkzeug.formparser import parse_form_data
from werkzeug.wsgi import get_input_stream
from io import BytesIO

class MethodMiddleware(object):
    """Don't actually do this. The disadvantages are not worth it."""
    def __init__(self, app):
        self.app = app

    def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
        if environ['REQUEST_METHOD'].upper() == 'POST':
            environ['wsgi.input'] = stream = \
                BytesIO(get_input_stream(environ).read())
            formdata = parse_form_data(environ)[1]
            stream.seek(0)

            method = formdata.get('_method', '').upper()
            if method in ('GET', 'POST', 'PUT', 'DELETE'):
                environ['REQUEST_METHOD'] = method

        return self.app(environ, start_response)
```

Comment: Thanks Markus, seems to be the case. Django itself doesn't seem to support it either. TastyPie does though (not using a _method, but using a header override), but could be adapted for forms.

As it stands, I'm just using post from forms and doing the PUT/POST/DELETE logic in the Flask view. Not as elegant as being able to use the routing decorator, but will have to do.

Thanks for your input.

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `MethodView` from `flask.views` and dispatch it to the right methods. I have created a simple Flask App to demonstrate it.

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify, request
from flask.views import MethodView

app = Flask(__name__)

class MyView(MethodView):

    def get(self):
        return jsonify({'method': 'GET'})

    def post(self):
        method = request.form.get('_method', 'POST')
        if method == 'POST':
            return jsonify({'method':method})
        else:
            if hasattr(self, method.lower()):            
                return getattr(self, method.lower())()
            else:
                return jsonify({'method': 'UNKNOWN'})

    def put(self):
        return jsonify({'method': 'PUT'})

    def delete(self):
        return jsonify({'method': 'DELETE'})

    def create(self):
        # NOT A HTTP VERB
        return jsonify({'method': 'CREATE'})

app.add_url_rule('/', view_func=MyView.as_view('myview'))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```