# How to handle a put request from the browser in Flask?

Tags: python, flask, hidden-field

Coming from an express.js background, I'm quite used to the method-override middleware which enables you to handle non browser supported HTTP verbs (e.g PUT, DELETE, etc) via a hidden input tag.

ex)

```
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
```

How do I mimic this middleware in Flask? Flask does not automatically handle these hidden inputs, so I am unable to process requests other than GET or POST. An excerpt of my code can be found below.

```
@blueprint.route('/news/<int:article_id>', methods=['GET','PUT','DELETE'])
def article(article_id):
if is_logged_in() and is_admin():
        if request.method == 'PUT':
            #do something

<form action="/news/{{ post.id }}" method="post">
    {{ form.hidden_tag() }}
    <input type="hidden" name="_method" value="PUT">
    {{ form.title.label }} {{ form.title }}
    {{ form.body.label }} {{ form.body }}
    {{ form.submit }}
</form>
```

Edit: Found a solution:
http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/38/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This doesn't really have anything to do with Flask (other than your templating engine came with it, I suppose) - you still have to generate an HTML page that will tell the browser to use **PUT**.

The HTML `form` element cannot be used for anything other than **POST** or **GET** directly, so any support for other methods should be done via `XMLHttpRequest` in javascript.

It is also possible to "tunnel" other request methods through **POST** by having a hidden field (as you have shown above) and having the server do the conversion for you, but it's not particularly efficient.  You can see an example of this in a [previous SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17233931/changing-request-method-using-hidden-field-method-in-flask), although I would not recommend this over `XMLHttpRequest` as it requires server support you probably shouldn't rely on.

Answer (score -2):

I think [flask-restful](http://flask-restful-cn.readthedocs.org/en/0.3.4/) will be a good choice for you,here is a simple example:

```
from flask import Flask, request
from flask_restful import Resource, Api

app = Flask(__name__)
api = Api(app)

todos = {}

class TodoSimple(Resource):
    def get(self, todo_id):
        return {todo_id: todos[todo_id]}

    def put(self, todo_id):
        todos[todo_id] = request.form['data']
        return {todo_id: todos[todo_id]}

api.add_resource(TodoSimple, '/<string:todo_id>')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

And I suggest you use some js libs that support (PUT,DELETE) method (eg, [jquery.rest](https://github.com/jpillora/jquery.rest))